# NetLogo set [energy] of one-of turtles

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create simple model in NetLogo where when two turtles meet, the one with the most energy give all its energy away to the second turtle.

I set up the command `meet` such as

```
to meet    
  ask turtles[ let candidate one-of turtles-at 1 0
    if candidate != nobody [

      if [energy] of candidate > energy [
        set color [color] of candidate
        set energy energy + [energy] of candidate
        set [energy] of candidate 0 ;; ISSUE HERE
      ]

   if [energy] of candidate < energy [
        set color [color] of candidate ;; ?
        set [energy] of candidate [energy] of candidate + energy 
        set energy 0 
      ]

    ]
  ]
```

So, I reset the energy of the turtle (ego) with `set energy energy + [energy] of candidate`, then I with: `set [energy] of candidate 0` but I can an error message: **This isn't something you can use "set" on**.

How I am suppose to reset the `candidate` energy during that transaction? Also during the second `if`, how do I set the candidate color to the (ego) turtles' own color? (`set color [color] of candidate`)

```
turtles-own[energy]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [  
    set pcolor gray  
  ]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 20

  ask turtles[
    set shape "wolf"
    set size 2

 set color one-of base-colors
 setxy random-xcor random-ycor

 set energy 10 + random 30
]
end

to go
  if max [energy] of turtles < 1 [ stop]
  tick
  move
  meet
end

to move
   ask turtles[ fd 1 right random 360 ]
 end

to meet    
  ask turtles[ let candidate one-of turtles-at 20 0
    if candidate != nobody [
      if [energy] of candidate > energy [
        set color [color] of candidate
        set energy energy + [energy] of candidate
        set [energy] of candidate 0 ;; HERE ISSUE
      ]

     if [energy] of candidate < energy [
        set color [color] of candidate
        set [energy] of candidate [energy] of candidate + energy 
        set energy 0 
       ]

    ]
  ] 
end
```

Comment: `ask candidate [ set energy 0 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set [...] of ...` syntax only exists in extremely old versions of NetLogo.

In current NetLogo, you do:

```
ask candidate [ set energy 0 ]
```